# ExtJS MVC make a window invisible from the controller

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I have the following situation, In an ExtJS MVC Controller I have the following lines that makes a custom window visible:

```
this.control({
    'grid_file button[action=change_settings]': {
        click: this.open_settings
    }
})
```

Further below:

```
open_settings: function() {
    this.getView('browser.storage_settings').create().show();
},
```

I want to add a cancel button to make this window invisible, how would I do that without adding an `id`? What would be the event listener and what would be the code inside the function?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an itemId (not the same as id) to access components with [`getComponent`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-method-getComponent) in a container.
The up() and down() methods are also a good way to retrieve components if you have a good structure.

The best way IMO to solve your problem is to define a button in your window like this:

```
buttons:[{
    text: 'Close',
    handler: function() {
        this.hide();
    }
}]
```

You can make a panel invisible with the [`.hide()`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-event-hide) method (look at the [`hideMode`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-hideMode) config too for more options).